# Creating dataframe with lambda & last_valid_index within a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Sara', 'Paul', 'Guest'], 'Interaction': ['share,like,share,like,like,like', 'love,like,share,like,love,like', 'share,like,share,like,like,like,share,like,share,like,like,hug','share,like,care,like,like,like']})
```

df:

```
    Name    Interaction
0   John    share,like,share,like,like,like
1   Sara    love,like,share,like,love,like
2   Paul    share,like,share,like,like,like,share,like,sha...
3   Guest   share,like,care,like,like,like
```

Then I separated interactions column by comma and expanding into columns per interaction:

```
expand = pd.concat([df, df['Interaction'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)
```

I got:

```
Name    Interaction     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   John    share,like,share,like,like,like     share   like    share   like    like    like    None    None    None    None    None    None
1   Sara    love,like,share,like,love,like  love    like    share   like    love    like    None    None    None    None    None    None
2   Paul    share,like,share,like,like,like,share,like,sha...   share   like    share   like    like    like    share   like    share   like    like    hug
3   Guest   share,like,care,like,like,like  share   like    care    like    like    like    None    None    None    None    None    None
```

Now I would like to tell the user what was the last interaction he/she did:

So, I tried to use `last_valid_index()`:

```
def lastint(df):
    if (df.apply(lambda s: s[s.last_valid_index()], axis=1).eq('like')):
         Name = df['Name']
         return (Name, 'The last activity of {} interactions was Like').format(Name)
```

Then create a new df for the whole users that have the same condition:

```
lastint = pd.DataFrame(list(df.apply(lastint).dropna()))
```

I should get the lastint df with just the name the return of the above function. instead I got:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

The expected output for `lastint` dataframe:

```
    0       1
0   John    The last activity of John interactions was Like
1   Sara    The last activity of Sara interactions was Like
3   Guest   The last activity of Guest interactions was Like
```

Thanks for help

Comment: can you post your expected output?

Comment: @AnuragDabas I edited the main post for the expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also do this by:

Firstly creates a copy of your df:

```
result=df[0:df.last_valid_index()+1].copy()
```

Now create a boolean mask via `rsplit()` and `eq()`:

```
cond=result['Interaction'].str.rsplit(',',1).str[1].eq('like')
```

Now pass that boolean mask and create a new column:

```
result.loc[cond,'Activity']= 'last activity of '+result.loc[cond,'Name']+' interactions was Like'
```

Finally use `drop()` and `dropna()` method:

```
result=result.drop('Interaction',1).dropna()
```

Now if you print `result` you will get:

```
print(result)

>>>


    Name    Activity
0   John    last activity of John interactions was Like
1   Sara    last activity of Sara interactions was Like
3   Guest   last activity of Guest interactions was Like
```

Comment: Yes this will help me to get the same result but the whole idea is to get the last non NaN after the expansion using `last_valid_index()`

Comment: `df.apply(lambda s: s[s.last_valid_index()], axis=1).eq('like')` how can I get the full df results after applying this condition? this might help me to filter the results in the df

Comment: updated answer...Kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last interaction like this:

`df['last_interaction'] = df['Interaction'].str.split(',').str[-1]`

Result:

```
> df[['Name', 'last_interaction']]

    Name    last_interaction
0   John    like
1   Sara    like
2   Paul    hug
3   Guest   like
```

Then adjust the column to fit your format.